# time synchronizer for many topics ros

Tags: ros, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have four different topics. I'm able to use timesynchronizer for two topics.

My question is can I use it for four topics at the same time?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238610/time-synchronizer-for-many-topics-ros/) by [b-sriram](https://answers.ros.org/users/26278/b-sriram/) on ROS Answers with karma: 105 on 2016-07-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, you can. In case you haven't seen them, a wiki for time sync is at http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters and a previous question with example is at http://answers.ros.org/question/60903/timesynchronizer-callback-problem/.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2016-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [b-sriram](https://answers.ros.org/users/26278/b-sriram/) on 2016-07-01**:
hi thanks, ya i got it working